# How to create a UIButton to appear same effect as UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I want to create a UIButton, but same appearence of a UIBarButtonItem. How to do it??

Comment: You need to have *images* that look like *UIBarButtonItems* and create the *UIButtons* with those images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to create buttons with the same appearence without using the Images, but adding only background colors and effects for it??

Comment: To my knowledge, it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of a navigation bar, the only way to create a button with the same style as a `UIBarButton` is to actually create the necessary background images yourself. There is no class that you may use for this (there is a class, obviously, but it's considered private API and using it will get your app rejected).

Answer (score 5):

Found this useful

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: Great tip. It's at for example Shared/UINavigationBarBlackOpaqueButton.png

Comment: Does anyone know the exact RGBA values to make UIButton look like  UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the renderMode on the button's image to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`. That will make it inherit the tintColor of its ancestor view.

Here's how to do it in Swift (for one control state, anyway):

```
if let i = myBtn?.imageForState(UIControlState.Normal) {
    if i.renderingMode != UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate {
        let newImage = i.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        myBtn?.setImage(newImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this via another forum .. a GradientButton class.

http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but in case someone comes accross this, there is also another possiblity without using images. I use QuartzCore instead.

This is what i do:

> MyUIButton.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MyUIButton : UIView { //i think you can also subclass from UIButton, but i use a view to be more flexible

    UIButton *_myInnerButton;
}

- (void) addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;

- (void) removeTarget:(id) target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;

@end
```

> MyUIButton.m

```
#import "MyUIButton.h"

@implementation MyUIButton


- (void) dealloc {

    if (_myInnerButton != nil) {

        [_myInnerbutton removeFromSuperview];

        _myInnerbutton = nil;
    }

    [super dealloc];
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        self.clipsToBounds = YES;


        _myInnerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [self addSubview:_myInnerButton];


        CGRect innerButtonRect = CGRectZero;

        innerButtonRect.size = self.frame.size;

        _myInnerButton.frame = innerButtonRect;


        CGRect iOSLookalikeViewRect = innerButtonRect;

        iOSLookalikeViewRect.origin.height = -innerButtonRect.size.height/2;


        UIView *iOSButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:iOSLookalikeViewRect];

        iOSButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 3;

        [self insertSubview:iOSButtonView belowSubview:_myInnerButton];

        UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3];

        UIColor *whiteColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.1];

        [self setGradientColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:whiteColor.CGColor, whiteColor2.CGColor, nil] forView:iOSButtonView];

        [iOSButtonView release];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setGradientColors:(NSArray*) gradientColors forView:(UIView*) view {

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = gradientColors;
    gradient.cornerRadius = view.layer.cornerRadius;

    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:1];

    [view.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]; //Optional for performance issues, can be removed also
}

//Implementation of the public methods not included, but just asign the methods to the _myInnerButton
@end
```

Hope it helps someone