# How to give UIButton the looks of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a hard time giving a UIButton the looks of a UIBarButtonItem(Save Button). Googling this, I found that this can be effectively done only by using images.
I have searched for images in the net and couldn't come up with any nice ones. Would be really helpful, if someone has got a link to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Teehan + Lax iPhone templates; they're quite good, and you'll find a good UIBarButtonItem in there:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Answer (score 1):

What about the [UIKit artwork extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor)?  It seems like it would return the easiest and most accurate button image.

Comment: What would be the exact RGBA values for blue save uibarbuttonitem

Comment: Exact?  The done button is a gradient.  There's a pattern image in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Extracted this from http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Set this image in your button and see the effect]

Set this image in your button and see the effect

Hope, this will you...

Comment: I need the blue "save" barbuttonitem

Answer (score 0):

I postet my solution at [How to create a UIButton to appear same effect as UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709136/how-to-create-a-uibutton-to-appear-same-effect-as-uibarbuttonitem/16810661#16810661)

I simply use QuartzCore Framework and provided an example also!

Hope it helps